# First Betti number of finitely non-co-hopfian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group.  Assume that $G$ is a finitely non-co-hopfian group in the sense that there is a group embedding $i: G\hookrightarrow G$ such that $1<[G\colon i(G)]<\infty$, is the first Betti number $b_1(G)$ always positive, i.e., the free part of the abelianization of $G$ has positive rank?

Comment: No: the infinite dihedral group $\langle x,z:x^2=1,xzx^{-1}=z^{-1}\rangle$ is a counterexample. Namely $x\mapsto x$, $z\mapsto z^2$ is an injective endomorphism whose image has index $2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: A second example for which every finite index subgroup has $b_1=0$: $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z})\ltimes\mathbf{Z}^3$ (endomorphism given by $(g,v)\mapsto (g,2v)$ onto a subgroup of index 8). This group has Kazhdan's Property T.

Comment: I would guess the opposite: the first Betti number of such a group is always $0$, with some trivial exceptions like $\Bbb Z^n$. At least I do not see non-trivial examples.

Comment: Actually the R.Thompson group $F$ has Abelianization of rank $2$ and a subgroup of index $2$ which is isomorphic to $F$. That is a non-trivial example.